# How do I express "Every" in manchester owl syntax?

Tags: logic, owl, protege, manchester-syntax

If A isRelatedTo B
and B has the dataproperty: existence = {true, false}

how can I express in manchester owl syntax (for protege) the subset where:
is type A and
every isRelatedTo of A has the value "true"

Comment: I don't understand how B is involved in the expression and how the property 'existence' is used. If they are important in your question, can you clarify how they interact?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're asking is how to write the class expression for the class whose members have type `A` and all of whose values for the `isRelatedTo` property is `true^^xsd:boolean`.  That's simple enough:

> A **and** (isRelatedTo **only** {true})

In Protégé it looks like this:

[image: "A and isRelatedTo only {true}" in the Protégé class expression editor]